# Tkinter keyboard event dosen't work with characters

Tags: python, tkinter, keyboard-events

[Raspberri PI 3 b+, Python]
First of all, I would apologizr gor my language skill.

I am coding the Tkinter for keyboard event, The keyboard command button like (Up) (Down) is work well but the normal charactors dosen't work (Such as 1-9, A-Z)

I have tired

```
frame.bind('<Left>', leftKey)      # THIS OK

frame.bind('<Right>', rightKey)    # THIS OK
```

but

```
frame.bind('<1>', leftKey)   # Not work

frame.bind('1', leftKey)     # Not work

frame.bind("1", leftKey)     # Not work
```

I would like to use keyboard charactor botton to works properly same as Up, Down button.

Comment: You can't use <1> or <2> for num keys you have to use <Key> which will call the function on any key, with proper `if` conditions you can achieve on what you trying. This link will help you - https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm

Comment: ****Regarding your link abobe****
<Key>
The user pressed any key. The key is provided in the char member of the event object passed to the callback (this is an empty string for special keys).

a
The user typed an “a”. Most printable characters can be used as is. The exceptions are space (<space>) and less than (<less>). Note that 1 is a keyboard binding, while <1> is a button binding.

So If I have to use <Key> and if condition. I don't understand what does  a described?

Comment: oh I see, the problem might be that your frame doesn't have the focus, try using `root.bind('1', leftkey)`

Comment: Wow, Ok I will try it. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Sorry if my question is quite innocent.
I try 
**root.bind('1', leftkey)**  and the result is root is not defined 

I changed to **frame.bind('1', leftKey), The program has no error but number 1 still dosen't work

I will be very appreciated if you could help me work it out. Thank you

Comment: `root` the main window, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"1"` and `'1'` should work. `"<1>"` represents mouse button 1.

If you are binding to a frame, you must make sure that it has keyboard focus. By default Frames do not have keyboard focus.

For example, to force the keyboard focus to a frame you need to call `focus_set`:

```
frame.focus_set()
```

Answer (score 0):

This could happen if the frame doesn't have the focus so `frame.bind('<1>', leftKey)` will not work.

You can check which widget has the focus by print `frame.focus_get()`.

### **There are two ways you can solve your problem.**

Either you set focus to the frame before binding callback

**Example:**

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

root.geometry('100x100+100+100')

frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()
frame.focus_set()   # This will get the frame in focus.

# If the frame is in focus the bind will work.
frame.bind( "1", lambda _: print(frame.focus_get()) )

root.mainloop()
```

**Or**

Just bind it to the main window.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk().  # Main window 

# bind the callback to the main window.
root.bind( '1', lambda k: print(k) )

root.mainloop()
```